# How can we tell visually if x-height is low,average or high?

Tags: typography

I've been reading this https://prowebtype.com/selecting-body-text/ and I found it extremely in terms of characteristics for body type selection. I have one question though: there's an example of Adobe Garamond having low x-height, but I wouldn't be able to tell by the example if it wasn't pointed out.How can we tell visually if they have a low,average or high x-height?

Best regards,
Carla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare an uppercase X and a lowercase x side by side. In general, the lowercase x will be slightly more than 1/2 the height of the capital X. If the lowercase x is smaller then that, you could consider it "low x-height." If the lowercase x is larger, you could consider it "high x-height."